# Pattern recognition (muscular activity)

Tags: math, arduino, signal-processing

I need a recommendation from your side. I am currently working with an EMG (muscle) sensor on Arduino and my target is to identify and measure a time of the muscular activity. On the picture below you find the raw data. [image: Serial plotter]  As you can see, during the muscular activity the range of the analog output is much higher. But I don't know which mathematical approach is suitable for this task.

Comment: Maybe average of absolute values and some threshold if it's too different from the long term average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sliding window...

1. **select window size**

   its a time in which you would analyze the signal properties. It should be long enough to hold at least one period of signal but 2-3 periods is better.
2. **now pass your signal through FIFO of size equal to your window size**

   after your FIFO is full at each new input value remove the first one from it and compute min and max of the FIFO content. Such FIFO is best implemented in form of cyclic buffer of fixed length. The difference of `max-min` is the dynamic range of the window and will tell you if your sensor detects activity or not.

   [image: windowed min/max]
3. **Threshold `max(t)-min(t)`**

   so for each computed window `t` compute:

   ```
   d(t) = max(t) - min(t)
   ```

   where `t` is the start time of your window. Now:

   ```
   if (d(t)>=threshold) muscle_is_working;
   ```

   the passive area in your signal has difference up do `~40` so set threshold to be bigger than that but smaller than active area in your signal for example

   ```
   threshold = 50
   ```

If you need more speed (as you are on god knows which MCU ... and yes Arduino is not a MCU its just framework) you can use abs sum of the window instead which does not require to process whole FIFO contents in each slide of window. Instead you just remove first item from sum and add the last one to it. So the equation would be:

```
d(t) = sum(i=t,...,t+size-1) of abs(signal(t)-inactive_average)
```

Also its a good idea to round up the window size to power of 2 so you can use bit operations instead of division and modulo in the cyclic buffer implementation.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer. I will try to finish it tomorrow or on Monday and will inform you about the results.